# Installing Ubuntu on Acer Iconia W510

Tags: system-installation, acer

I want to buy the most modern touch screen laptop, Acer Iconia W510, but I will buy only if I can install Ubuntu on it. I was not able to find the answer when I searched. Does anyone know whether I can install the latest version of Ubuntu on this device?

Comment: What have you found using Google and the search here? I mean, `Acer Iconia W510 Ubuntu` gives quite some results to look into.

Answer (score 0):

You can't boot a linux kernel currently on that processor. The intel atom z2760 does not work with linux period.

Comment: Please add a link to the source of your information about the Intel Atom z2760 processor to your answer.

Comment: Verified that the CPU doesn't work on Linux: it's a SOC, even on Windows it requires drivers to be used correctly, and it's the reason modern windows 10 version don't work on it. Even Microsoft gave up on that POS